# Порядок вычислений выражений

Tags: c#, функции

Фиксирован ли порядок вычислений выражений?

```
using System;

class Program 
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 
        int tmp = 0;
        Console.Write(Test.Foo1(ref tmp)+Test.Foo2(ref tmp)*Test.Foo1(ref tmp)); 
    } 
}

class Test 
{ 
    public static int Foo1(ref int a)
    {
        Console.Write(a + " ");
        return (a += 2);
    }
    public static int Foo2(ref int a)
    {
        Console.Write(a + " ");
        return (a += 3);
    }
}
```

Выведется

```
0 2 5 37
```

Вычисляется слева направо. Но можно ли быть в этом уверенным?

Comment: >Но можно ли быть в этом уверенным?

ваши сомнения на чем-то основаны?

Comment: Есть такая штука, как [порядок выполнения операторов]. Он никогда не меняется и, если в нем разобраться, пару раз поможет распутать баги.

Comment: Сомнения основаны на теме связанной с С++ на msdn
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ru-RU/f34e7f98-4291-4369-85dc-df82bde5c510/-ccli?forum=programminglanguageru
"Т.е. никто и никогда не даст вам 100% гарантию того, что первым будет вычислен первый аргумент – i++, а вторым – i + 2. Т.е. результат может быть как: -2, так и 1. Это относится к C# в том числе."
 
Или это касается исключительно аргументов функций?

Comment: мы изначально говорили о немного разных вещах. Поправил ответ

Comment: Про точки следования и undefined и unspecified behavior

* http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2005/11/sequence-points.html плюс комментарии
* http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2005/08/unspecified-behavior-undefined.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Порядок вычисления аргументов методов определен в пункте 7.5.1.2 стандарта:

> 7.5.1.2 Run-time evaluation of argument lists
> During the run-time processing of a function member invocation (§7.5.4), the expressions or variable references of an argument list are evaluated in order, from left to right

То есть параметры вычисляются слева направо. Получается, что либо ошибается стандарт, либо тот человек, с форума msdn, на чьи слова вы ссылались.

Однако существует такое понятие, как побочные эффекты функций. Так вот помимо вышесказанного необходимо, чтобы функции (а с ними и их побочные эффекты) выполнялись в той очередности, в которой объявлены, а параметры передавались слева направо в соответствии с сигнатурой. Например:

```
public static void Write(int i, int b) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", i, b);
}

public static int First(ref int i) {
    Console.WriteLine("first");
    return ++i;
}

public static int Second(ref int i) {
    Console.WriteLine("second");
    i += 2;
    return i;
}

int i = 5;

i = 5;
/*
тут все логично, выведет строки  
first
second
6 8
потому что сначала First вернет ++i (то есть 6)
а затем Second вернет i + 2 (то есть 8)
*/
Write(First(ref i), Second(ref i));

i = 5;
/* 
а вот тут выведет 
first
second
8 6
и результат может быть неожиданным, 
потому что компилятор сначала выполняет первую функцию, 
занося ее результат во второй параметр, 
а затем вторую, занося ее результат в первый параметр
*/
Write(b: First(ref i), i: Second(ref i));
```

Что касается операторов: у каждого оператора в C# (как и в других языках) есть свой приоритет и ассоциативность (он же порядок выполнения). Кроме того, C# в отличие от С++ лишен всяческих  источников головной боли, связанных с UB, а потому всегда можно предсказать порядок выполнения и резуьтат выражения (хотя для человека это подчас нетривиальная и запутанная задача). Большая часть операторов в C# левоассоциативны (то есть выполняются слева направо). Однако не все (например, оператор присваивания выполняется справа налево). Подробнее о приоритете и ассоциативности можно почитать [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx)

Напоследок стоит заметить, что усложнять себе жизнь таким кодом, как вы привели выше, не стоит - компилятор способен разобрать это без труда, а вот человеку гораздо сложнее. Думаю, выпадать в осадок после часовой отладки багов, связанных с неверно рассчитанным приоритетом операций и побочными действиями функций (а в вашем коде есть и такое, что в общем-то тоже не приветствуется) - это далеко не предел мечтаний в работе программиста. Поэтому в подобных ситуациях лучше не жалеть скобочек для группировки операций - компилятор сожрёт, а человеку читать будет легче. Ну или даже разбивать операции на отдельные выражения

Comment: Order of evaluation != associativity. Даже у правоассоциативных операторов аргументы будут вычислены слева направо.

Comment: Спасибо, интересный пример.